# What do all of the items in the output from p2pool mean?

Tags: mining-pools, p2pool

```
2012-08-15 10:57:04.728547 P2Pool: 17401 shares in chain (9127 verified/17405 total) Peers: 11 (0 incoming)
2012-08-15 10:57:04.728781  Local: 1689MH/s in last 10.0 minutes Local dead on arrival: ~3.8% (2-8%) Expected time to share: 29.8 minutes
2012-08-15 10:57:04.728886  Shares: 3 (1 orphan, 0 dead) Stale rate: ~33.3% (6-80%) Efficiency: ~73.5% (22-104%) Current payout: 0.0174 BTC
2012-08-15 10:57:04.728999  Pool: 415GH/s Stale rate: 9.3% Expected time to block: 6.3 hours
```

Most of it is evident, but if someone could give a breakdown, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
P2Pool: 17401 shares in chain (9127 verified/17405 total) Peers: 11 (0 incoming)
```

This means that P2Pool knows of 17405 shares, 9127 of which have been verified (indicating that you haven't been running p2pool for more than 24 hours), and 17401 of which are in the selected chain (meaning that there have been 4 orphaned shares globally in the past few minutes).

```
Local: 1689MH/s in last 10.0 minutes Local dead on arrival: ~3.8% (2-8%) Expected time to share: 29.8 minutes
```

You have 1689MH/s mining, with 3.8% of shares invalid due to latency between P2Pool and the miner. It's expected that you'll get your next share in half an hour.

```
Shares: 3 (1 orphan, 0 dead) Stale rate: ~33.3% (6-80%) Efficiency: ~73.5% (22-104%) Current payout: 0.0174 BTC
```

You found 3 shares, one of which was orphaned (33.3% of them), indicating that your normal stale rate if you continue falls between 6% and 80%, with 95% confidence. Your efficiency is 73.5%, meaning that you'll only get 73.5% of what you should, based on your stales, though in the future, the true value will fall between 22% and 104% with 95% confidence, so there's no evidence currently that something is wrong (since 100% is in that interval).

```
Pool: 415GH/s Stale rate: 9.3% Expected time to block: 6.3 hours
```

The pool has a total of 415GH/s of hashing power, and 9.3% of discovered shares aren't integrated into the sharechain. It's expected that we'll get a block in 6 hours.